# No qualifying bean of type [leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService] found for dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to run the batch but I was not able to inject the batchservice into it.

BatchApplication.java

```
package leanbizapps.dexter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import leanbizapps.monster.config.SwaggerConfig;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,SwaggerConfig.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
 public class BatchApplication {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(BatchApplication.class);
     ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
}
}
```

LeaveAllocationJobConfiguration.java

```
package leanbizapps.dexter.jobs;
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class LeaveAllocationJobConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Autowired
private BatchService batchService;

@Bean
public ItemReader<LeaveSetting> reader() {
    JpaPagingItemReader<LeaveSetting> leaveSettingReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<LeaveSetting>();
    leaveSettingReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    leaveSettingReader.setQueryString("from LeaveSetting");
    return leaveSettingReader;
}

@Bean
public Job addLeaveAllocationJob() {
    return jobs.get("addLeaveAllocationJob").listener(protocolListener()).start(step()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step step() {
    
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<LeaveSetting, Boolean> chunk(1).reader(reader()).processor(processor())
            .writer(writer()).build();
}


@Bean
public ItemWriter<? super Boolean> writer() {
    return new ItemWriter<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends Boolean> items) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Processing " + items);
            
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<LeaveSetting, Boolean> processor() {
    return new ItemProcessor<LeaveSetting, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean process(LeaveSetting leavesetting) throws Exception {
            int count =0;
            while(count>0){
                LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                batchService.leaveBatch(localDateTime);
            }
            return true;
        }
        
    };
}

@Bean
public ProtocolListener protocolListener() {
    return new ProtocolListener();
}

}
```

When I run this code I'm getting no qualifier bean type error. `No qualifying bean of type [leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'leaveAllocationJobConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService leanbizapps.dexter.jobs.LeaveAllocationJobConfiguration.batchService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
> at leanbizapps.dexter.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService leanbizapps.dexter.jobs.LeaveAllocationJobConfiguration.batchService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> ... 15 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [leanbizapps.monster.services.BatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
> ... 17 common frames omitted

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: any reason you rolled back my revision? I only added syntax highlighting, made sure the code blocks are properly formatted and formatted your error as a code block because this is hardly readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"leanbizapps.monster", "leanbizapps.dexter"})
public class BatchApplication {
// source code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide your `BatchService`, but it appears to be in the package `leanbizzapps.monster.services`, while your main class resides in the `leanbizzapps.dexter` package.

Spring boot will automatically scan all **sub**packages, however, it will not scan other packages (like `leanbizzapps.monster.services`).

The solution is to restructure the application so that `BatchApplication` is in the parent package of all beans (so you could move it to the `leanbizzapps` package for example).

The alternative is to include the `leanbizzapps.monster.services` package in any `@ComponentScan`, for example on your main class:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "leanbizzapps.monster.services", "leanbizzapps.dexter" })
public class BatchApplication {
    // ...
}
```